# Determine the distribution function of a random variable

Tags: probability

I am a bit lost with the following exercise, I would really appreciate your help:

$$
f_X,_Y(x,y)
\begin{cases}
  c & x^2 + y^2\leq 4\\    
  0 & otherwise    
\end{cases} 
$$

What is the distribution function of :

$$ 
\theta= 
\begin{cases}
  arctan \frac{X}{Y} & X \ne 0\\    
  0 & X=0    
\end{cases} 
$$

Well, I don't even have a clue of how to start with this one. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that since $$\int f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy=1$$we obtain $$c={1\over 4\pi}$$and since the PDF is a circle (more precisely a cylinder) and is maintained under rotation then the distribution of $\theta$ is uniform, i.e.$$\theta\sim U\left(-{\pi\over 2},{\pi\over 2}\right)$$according to standard definition of $\arctan$.

Comment: could you please clarify the rotation thing? I am not sure how you could decide that $arctan \frac{X}{Y}$ is distributed uniformly

Comment: Surely $\theta$ is radial. Since no radius of circle is distinguishable from the others and the PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is uniform we argue that so must be that of $\theta$